# django static error in bash linux command

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 221, in makedirs

```
mkdir(name, mode)
```

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/static'

Comment: *when i m trying to run python manage.py collectstatic this error comes i dont know why i set up an environment set up the permission then also error comes*

Comment: It's what the error message says: You don't have permission to create the directory `/static`. Note that the `/` indicates that you are trying to create a directory at the root level of your filesystem which is almost certainly an incorrect configuration.